# Visual Studio 2013 intellisense not working for cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, intellisense

I just started a new dot net 4.5.1 project with MVC 5.2.3 and my intellisense is not working for cshtml files. `ViewBag.Title` gives the error, `one or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found`. The actual website will compile and load though. So the only issue is the intellisense. I have tried removing and adding the c# reference. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

So I have no clue how this fixed it but I switched to dot net 4.5.0 and back to 4.5.1 and now its fixed.